# How to order by items based on data from two mysql tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: *users (username,points,....)* and *items(id,author-username,....)*
Now I have only this: `(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` - I check an element for multiple keywords
But I want to sort the items based on how related is to `$keyword` and the same time how much points the author of the item has.

For example if an item is related to 2 keywords and the author of it has 5 points the item will be rated with 7 points

How it`s possible to do this ? Any ideas ?

Comment: you can use full-text searches to find out how well a column matches a string: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate a custom sort field from a number of data fields or computations, e.g.:

```
SELECT
  a.name,
  b.score,
  CONCAT(a.company, FORMAT(b.score * b.handicap, 0)) AS sortfield
FROM a,b
WHERE ...
SORT BY sortfield
```